# relationship between independent multivariate normal vectors and covariance of some components being zero

Tags: statistics, asymptotics, independence

About problem 2.8 from https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/b.j.k.kleijn/AsympStat-LecNotes2010.pdf

Hey anyone, I have a question about problem 2.8 from the link above, or a copy here:

"Let $(X_1,...,X_k,Y_1,...,Y_{\ell})$ be multivariate-normally distributed. Show that $(X_1,...,X_k)$ and $(Y_1,...,Y_{\ell})$ are independent iff Cov$(X_i,Y_j)=0$ $\forall i,j$.

The right direction is trivial (I find it trivial), but the left one requires more work. I have shown that $X_i$ and $Y_j$ are independent $\forall i,j$ as follows:

Since $X:=(X_1,...,X_k,Y_1,...,Y_{\ell})$ is multivariate normally distributed, then $a^T X$ is normally distributed for any real vector $a$ (lemma 2.4). So this is also true for an $a$ with exactly two coordinates $\neq 0$. So $(X_i,Y_j)$ is multivariate normally distributed (lemma 2.4). Because it also holds by assumption that Cov$(X_i,Y_j)=0$, then $X_i$ is independent of $Y_j$ (lemma 2.6).

But it is not true in general that also the vectors are independent. Can anyone see why it is so in this case? I am supposed not to say "thanks" in the comments, so I thank in advance here.

Comment: The unique variant is to write pdf of large vector and show that zero covariance implies that it is equal to the product of pdf's of subvectors. This should be a simple consequence of the structure of covariance matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the covariance matrix of $Z=(X_1, X_2, \dots X_k, Y_1, Y_2, \dots ,Y_l)$ looks loke this:
$$\Sigma =\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
\Sigma_1 &0\\
0 & \Sigma_2\end{array} } \right]$$

where $\Sigma_1$ is the covariance matrix of $X=(X_1, X_2, \dots X_k)$ and $\Sigma_2$ is the covariance matrix of $Y=(Y_1, Y_2, \dots ,Y_l)$

Now expand the exponent part of the pdf of $(X_1, X_2, \dots X_k, Y_1, Y_2, \dots ,Y_l)$, ie $$Z'\Sigma Z=(X,Y)'\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
\Sigma_1 &0\\
0 & \Sigma_2\end{array} } \right] (X,Y) =X'\Sigma_1 X +Y'\Sigma_2 Y$$

Then pdf$(Z)$=pdf$(X)$$\times$ pdf$(Y)$, which follows the proof the problem.

Comment: Oh ok, it's actually the tool pdf($X$)pdf($Y$)=pdf($(X,Y)$) iff X and Y are independent. I did not forget this tool, but forgot that I know this. Maybe it was a long time ago when I worked with that, but from now on I'll keep this in my mind for later problems.

Comment: Ha ha!! Btw what do you do? (I mean job or research etc.)

Comment: I study mathematics at the University of Amsterdam, and what do you do?

Comment: Masters completed(Statistics), hoping for PhD

Comment: PhD would be great. In what way do they select PhD people? I am finishing my bachelor. Next year my plan is master stochastics. But I'm already doing Asymptotic statistics without signing up, and have already done all the exercises from a subject called Measure theoretic probability. Why I'm studying in this way is a long story, maybe a bit too long for a comment like this.

Comment: About PhD, I have no idea because I am from India and I don't know things are same here and there. Here first you have to qualify then you have to do some course. After that you select an adviser who favors your topic, and continue your PhD.

Answer (score 0):

$X= (X_1, X_2, \dots X_k)$ and $Y= (Y_1, Y_2, \dots , Y_l)$ are independent. Then $\text{Cov}(a'X,  b'Y)=0$ for any $a\in \mathbb{R}^k$ and any $b\in \mathbb{R}^l$.

Take $a=(0,0, \dots ,1, \dots , 0)$($1$ is in $i$ -th position) and $b=(0,0, \dots ,1, \dots , 0)$($1$ is in $j$ -th position), we will have the proof of the 'only if' part.

Comment: Ok, but  "the right direction is trivial (I find it trivial)", i.o.w. I mean the "$\Rightarrow$" part is trivial. My problem is to determine in the "$\Leftarrow$" direction that the vectors X and Y are independent, and I already have $X_i$ and $Y_j$ independent.

Comment: Okk, wait then.

Comment: It's done @RoccovanVreumingen